# Implementing a 'toast' feature that's cross platform

Tags: nativescript

I was thinking of a small layout that slides up from the bottom of the
page and disappears after sometime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is this plugin I've worked on for the Material Design Snackbar: https://github.com/bradmartin/nativescript-snackbar

There is also the `Toast` plugin: https://github.com/TobiasHennig/nativescript-toast at one time the plugin dropped iOS support but it looks like a recent contribution was made to fix the iOS version. Since there is not a native toast for iOS from apple, this plugin uses a cocoapod for that platform it looks like.

If you wanted to use your own visuals you could always create a layout that's positioned off the screen using the `translate (x) or (y)` and then animate it into the view when you want and out after a set time. The possibilites are limitless really.